# Subscribing to multiple observables sequentially with Rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to make a http request **only** when my form is dirty. I tried using zip but it will still make the http request regardless as the pipe results will only apply on the subscribe block. Is there anyway for me to **NOT** nest the observables as I have to subscribe to another observable after the http call which will result is 3 nested layers of observable.

```
  @ViewChild('form') 
  form: NgForm;

  // only take events when form is dirty
  const formValueChanges$ = this.form.valueChanges
    .pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      filter(() => this.form.dirty),
      takeUntil(this._destroy$),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      tap(result => {
        console.log(result);
      })
    );

  // http request returning an observable
  const updateForm$ = this.tempService.update();

  zip(formValueChanges$, updateForm$)
    .subscribe((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      }
    );
```

**Intended Behaviour**

```
this.form.valueChanges
  .pipe(
     debounceTime(500),
     filter(() => this.form.dirty),
     takeUntil(this._destroy$),
     distinctUntilChanged(),
  ).subscribe(() => {
     console.log("SAVED");
     this.tempService.update().subscribe();
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **concatMap** operator to be sure of the order, concatMap will wait for previous HTTP Observable to complete before mapping the new value from the form.

```
this.form.valueChanges
 .pipe(
  debounceTime(500),
  filter(() => this.form.dirty),
  takeUntil(this._destroy$),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  concatMap(val => this.tempService.update())
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go for mergeMap Operator from rxjs.